# Chnage asp.net button text permanently using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi hope this is an easy one. So help me.
i have asp.net button. based upon the input values given to javascript function I want to change the asp.net button value permanently. Even if the page post backs, it should not affect.

Comment: What if the browser window is closed and opened later? If you want the change to persist, you need to save it at some place and add the text to button on page load

Comment: No no. I meant during the post backs.

Comment: value? do you mean text?

Comment: Yes. I want to change the Text property of the asp.net Button control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from the above description is you want to change the "Button" text through java script and it should not change, when user post-back page to server. If yes then this solution might helpful for you but below solution will not work, if browser closed and open again.

According to me the best way to persist the value is storing into **hidden field**, which will be posted every time when your page post backs. So it will never change until your code will not modified it for e.g.:

```
**ASPX PAGE :**

asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:xyz()" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

**JavaScript:**
<script>
    var value = document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value;
    document.getElementById("Button1").value = value;
    function xyz() {
        document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = 'world';
    }
</script>

**Code Behind [C#]:**
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                HiddenField1.Value = "Hello";
            }
        }
```

In an above code, when user clicks button then its value (World) will stored into hidden field and set as title through javascript otherwise it will display default value (Hello).

hope this helps !!

Comment: Yeah Thanks, Rahul. I too tried once like this. But I forgot. Thanks for answering to me.:)

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be the easiest using jquery. The code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#button_id").val(new_value);
});
```